# How can I apply limit query from a specific row in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have businessdates table where dates are in ascending order (but not consecutive, because some dates are holidays). Following query works perfect if I have to select a date after skipping '?' dates from the last row in the table

```
         SELECT  date   FROM  businessdates    order by  date desc  limit ?,1 ;
```

(I bind '?' in query from java code)

Question: Instead of skipping from the last row, how can I skip from somewhere in the middle of the table based on some known date. I am guessing something like below  , and would appreciate any suggestions

```
         SELECT  date   FROM  (select * from businessdates where date <= "somedate")     order by  date desc  limit ?,1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the `OFFSET` keyword.

```
SELECT  date
FROM  businessdates
ORDER BY  date DESC  
LIMIT 1, OFFSET n ;
```

This will start the search at the `nth` row. Substitute n for whatever row number you want to start the search from.

> The OFFSET clause in a SELECT query causes the result set to start some number of rows after the logical first item.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_offset.html

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown should work just fine. You may probably want to use `between` conditional operator to get the specific range and then limit it like

```
SELECT  `date`
FROM  businessdates 
where `date` between 'somedate' and 'otherdate'
order by  `date` desc
limit ?,1;
```